# JQuery - Submit array of data along with a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have form on the page, in the background I gather make an array of data that I want to pass to a back end controller. I can $post but I don't want the request to be ajax. I want to submit the array along with form, when the user presses the submit button. Does Javascript allow this anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe if you donot want to use ajax.

To POST to an iframe you must use form target.

Sample code :

```
<form
      id="moodleform" target="iframe"
      method="post" action="http://www.example.com/login/index.php"
>
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="guest"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="guest"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="testcookies" value="1"/>
</form>
<iframe name="iframe"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('moodleform').submit();
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure how this answer is related to the question.

Comment: @awexfwex "I don't want the request to be ajax. I want to submit the array along with form"...He donot want to use ajax to post data.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a hidden field that you populate with a serialized version of the data?
Alternatively, you could have multiple hidden input form elements with the same name, which (back-end application dependant) should give you the POST variable as an array of values.
Building on that, you could add the hidden input elements dynamically to the form.

Comment: The array that im trying to send has almost 300 entries. So, I should create 300 hidden fields and assign their values? Is this the only way?